# Creating new instance with same variable name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

What will happen if I create new instance of an object with the same variable name:

```
var obj;
var Abc = function(params){
    .....
}

obj = new Abc(params);

setInterval(createNewObj,10000);

var createNewObj = function (){
   obj = new Abc(params);
}
```

What will happen when I create new instance  of Abc (with same of different parameters)? Will this have any memory issues?
What will really happened?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you doing with `obj`? Whether you'll get memory issues depends on the code that you've not shown to us

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special will happen.

Every 10 seconds or so, the event handler will create a new instance of `Abc` and "de-ref" the old one which will be garbage collected sometime afterwards.